# Solidity: Internal or recursive type is not allowed for public state variables, Cannot Expose public mapping containing struct

Tags: solidity

I don't understand why this doesn't work when I can see it works in the existing [bravo contracts](https://github.com/compound-finance/compound-protocol/blob/a3214f67b73310d547e00fc578e8355911c9d376/contracts/Governance/GovernorBravoInterfaces.sol#L93)

I'm trying to support inhertance of a public property I have structs that look like so:

```
abstract contract Governance {
    struct Proposal {
      /// @notice Unique id for looking up a proposal
      uint id;

      /// @notice Creator of the proposal
      address proposer;

      /// @notice the ordered list of target addresses for calls to be made
      address[] targets;

      /// @notice Receipts of ballots for the entire set of voters
      mapping (address => Receipt) receipts;

     //...
  }

  /// @notice Ballot receipt record for a voter
  struct Receipt {
    /// @notice Whether or not a vote has been cast
    bool hasVoted;

    /// @notice Whether or not the voter supports the proposal or abstains
    uint8 support;

    /// @notice The number of votes the voter had, which were cast
    uint96 votes;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to expose a public mapping like so:

```
mapping(uint256 => ProposalVote) public bravoProposals;
```

When I try to expose this I get an error:

> TypeError: Internal or recursive type is not allowed for public state variables.

I'm using solidity `0.8.9`? This should work, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this is the case, but it seems solidity can't expose public mapping whose do not start at a "definitive" point

By adding an arbitrary value with a definitive length, it can be exposed.

```
struct ProposalVote {
    bool isTrue;
    uint256[] votes;
    mapping(address => bool) hasVoted;
}
```

**Note:** This answer is based on observations and I would prefer a better answer